# Apache2 error log

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I can't seem to find the error log for apache on my locahost on Ubuntu. I have apache2 installed.

I'm using this command to follow the errors `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` but somehow this log is not logging all my errors?

Is this the correct file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `httpd.conf` to see if you have the following line or something very similiar:

```
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
```

It might be in a different directory, or it might be called something else, but if you don't have a line in the Apache configuration file starting with `ErrorLog`, you're probably not catching the errors.

If that's good, double-check to make sure you haven't got the `LogLevel` commented out:

```
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn
```

The default setting is `warn`, which is about on the edge of way too much info and waiting for a more serious fault in the `localhost`. If it's commented out, with a hash (#) starting the line, you also won't be catching any errors in the log file despite the `ErrorLog` setting.

You can compare what each level setting of `LogLevel` is in the [Apache server documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel).

Comment: It seems like I'm in the correct file but I noticed something else.

In the httpd.conf file I noticed the following
#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

Could this have something to do with the strictness of the errors?

Comment: That would be correct, and if commented out, will mean you're not catching any of the errors.